# XDK android deployment

Tags: android, intel-xdk

It is possible- in XDK to emulate this simple thing, starting with an XDK stub then inserting a body..

```
<!DOCTYPE html><!--HTML5 doctype-->
<html>
<head>
    <title>Your New Application</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0" />
    <style type="text/css">
        /* Prevent copy paste for all elements except text fields */
        *  { -webkit-user-select:none; -webkit-tap-highlight-color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0); }
        input, textarea  { -webkit-user-select:text; }
        body { background-color:white; color:black }
    </style>
    <script src='intelxdk.js'></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        /* This code is used to run as soon as Intel activates */
        var onDeviceReady=function(){
        //hide splash screen
        intel.xdk.device.hideSplashScreen();
        };
        document.addEventListener("intel.xdk.device.ready",onDeviceReady,false);
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="game" width=300 height=300></canvas>
  <script type="text/javascript"> (function() {
  var ctx, noise;

  ctx = document.getElementById("game").getContext("2d");

  ctx.fillStyle = "#000";

  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 300, 300);

  noise = function() {
    var color, x, y, _i, _results;
    _results = [];
    for (x = _i = 0; _i <= 20; x = ++_i) {
      _results.push((function() {
        var _j, _results1;
        _results1 = [];
        for (y = _j = 0; _j <= 20; y = ++_j) {
          color = Math.floor(Math.random() * 360);
          ctx.fillStyle = "hsl(" + color + ", 60%, 50%)";
          _results1.push(ctx.fillRect(x * 15, y * 15, 14, 14));
        }
        return _results1;
      })());
    }
    return _results;
  };
    alert(ctx.canvas.width.toString());
  setInterval(noise, 100);

}).call(this);
</script>

</body>
</html
```

---Building also works fine but when deploying the .apk to an Android-11 device it's 
just blank.

Also: deploying XDK sample projects works OK

Comment: Are you able to open the app in AppPreview on Android?

Comment: Android 11 corresponds to Android 3.0, which is a very rare beast and difficult to test, since it is difficult to find such a device. Do you get similar results on Android 2.3.5 devices?

Answer (score 1):

Canvas is not supported by the simple Android WebView before Android 4.4 (API 19).

You need to use "Crosswalk for Android". You can find it on the "build menu".